# Fixed position CSS for an image in a table cell

Tags: css, image, css-tables

I have a little issue with images in table cell. I have a table with 3 rows. In the middle row, I have a picture (which is a link, so no background). I would like to put a second picture partially over the first one (like a stamp), without changing the size of the cell. It needs to be in the corner of the cell.

See this example of what I need:

[image: See this example of what I need].

I would like to avoid absolute positioning because I have few tables on the page. Some need the stamp and some don't.

I tried this with `position:relative`, but it changes the size of the cell putting the picture under the first one.

Can you help me?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I've created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/imacange/x706p9y7/2/) for you.

Image B is on top of Image A and Image A is clickable and both are of course in a table cell, exactly like you wanted.

The only thing I did not solve is the `position: absolute`
I know that you did not want to use that but I honestly don't see any other way to do it.
You could use position: fixed but as soon as the user will scroll down, the table will go away below the pictures and you'll have these pictures on top of your whole page.

I hope that helps you. Cheers.

```css
table, tr, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
tbody tr td {
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px; 
}
.footer td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
.back {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 400px;
  margin: -130px 0 0 50px;
}
.front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 75px 0 0 352px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<theader>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=2>HEADER</th>
  </tr>
  </theader>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>
    <a href="#"><img class="back" src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/rock600x400.jpg"></a>
      <img class="front" src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/lights600x400.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tr class="footer">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```